# How to fix build error with FBSDKLoginKit in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

My ios app was working fine until I ran "pod install" and updated all of my pods.  I'm now getting an error when trying to build in Xcode.

```
FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.m:43:25: No known class method for selector 'dictionary:setObject:forKey:'
```

Here are the FB pod versions used:

```
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (5.0.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.44.1)
```

Those are not specified in my podfile.  I think they're installed as part of FirebaseAuth which is in my podfile.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.44'` to the Podfile.

There's a bug in the 4.x versions of `FBSDKLoginKit`. Its podspec allow major version updates to its `FBSDKCoreKit` dependency, but the code doesn't comply.

There's no FBSDKCoreKit version specified in the [4.44.1 version](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/4.44.1/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json#L67) like there is in the [5.0.0 version](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/5.0.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json#L65).

The suggested Podfile change is a workaround for the podspec problem.

The current version of FirebaseUI requires version 4.x of FBSDKLoginKit.

Comment: An updated version of `FirebaseUI` that works with `FBSDKCoreKit 5.x` is now available - so `pod update` should now be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to also fix the version of `Firebase/Core`, like following.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.35'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.35'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20'
```

**Additionally information**

The above case is that you have `FirebaseUI/Twitter` for Twitter login, which is using TwitterKit internally. But TwitterKit is finished to support. So if you have already used FirebaseUI/Twitter, the following should be used

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth'
```

instead of the below.

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
```

At the result, we can use the latest & stable FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit and Firebase/Core.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. It is after installing FBSDKCoreKit 5.0.0 (was 4.44.1) as part of the Firebase codebase.

It seems that there may be some code that Firebase use:

- (void)addLoggingExtra:(id)object forKey:(id)key
  {
  [FBSDKInternalUtility dictionary:_mutableLoggingExtras setObject:object forKey:key];
  }

That seem to be problematic and gives the error:
No known class method for selector 'dictionary:setObject:forKey:'

While I don't know how to solve it, the above may provide insights to others.

Answer (score 1):

the above answer marked as correct didn't work for me.
this is how I fixed this error. First I downloaded iOS sdk from facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios?sdk=fbsdk

then I opened downloaded sdk and copied FBSDKCorekit.framework, FBSDKLoginKit.framework, and Bolts.framework into 'Frameworks' folder in my Xcode project.

(I'm not using facebook to login at this time but I was still getting the same error as you guys are)

At last I changed my pod to:

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'

update  pod, clean project and rebuild

a couple errors pop up for deprecated code in the fb sdk. click 'fix' from the error and project runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Very first you need to proper check version of pod which you are installing. Because it looks that you are installing earlier version of `Facebook Pod`. Please look at screenshot I have attached. It's work fine for me.

[image]

Though you can follow these steps to overcome this error.

- Comment All Facebook pods in pod file.
- Now close Xcode project, clear all recent items, Quit Xcode. Clean derived data.
- Go to `Terminal`, jump to your project path directory, run command `pod install` (It will remove all Facebook pods).
- Please save or commit your code if you are using versioning system.
- Now open your Xcode project and go to pod file.
- Copy latest pods from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/componentsdks/) and paste into pod file.
- Now again close Xcode project, clear all recent items, Quit Xcode. (Please don't build or run project)
- Go to `Terminal` and run command `pod install` (It will install all latest Facebook pods).
- Don't forget to save or commit code.
- Then open Xcode project, clean folder, build and then run.