# Creating unit tests for Xcode project results in error : Showing Recent Messages :-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKCodelessIndexer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

When adding this to my pods file ( for unit testing purposes )

```
target 'MY_PROJECT_TITLE_Tests' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'Firebase'
end
```

I get the error when compiling:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKCodelessIndexer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FBSDKMarketingKit(FBSDKButtonIndexer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

there were no errors prior to the "pod install" of the above podfile change. Why is this / is there a fix? thank you.

Comment: Are you using facebook sdk ? because `FBSDKMarketingKit` is class of facebook sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a `pod update` is needed.

There could be an incompatibility between old versions of Firebase and FBSDK like [How to fix build error with FBSDKLoginKit in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986325/how-to-fix-build-error-with-fbsdkloginkit-in-xcode/55987801#55987801)