# Login with facebook error on iOS in flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, flutter

I wrote a flutter login with facebook app.

It works correctly on Android.
On iOS simulator and on real iPhone device it does not work. Both having iOS 13.2.

pub spec.yaml file

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.3.1
```

main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isLogged = false;
  FirebaseUser myUser;

  Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook() async {
    var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
    var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
    debugPrint(result.status.toString());
    if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
      FirebaseUser user =
          await _auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
      return user;
    }
    return null;
  }

  void _login() {
    _loginWithFacebook().then((response) {
      if (response != null) {
        myUser = response;
        setState(() {
          isLogged = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _logout() async {
    await _auth.signOut().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        isLogged = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Login App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(isLogged ? 'Profile Page' : 'Login App'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: _logout,
              icon: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: isLogged
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Name: ' + myUser.displayName),
                    Image.network(myUser.photoUrl),
                  ],
                )
              : FacebookSignInButton(
                  onPressed: _login,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I added the plist file in the Xcode project correctly. And configured the iOS version of the Facebook developer correctly based on the following steps:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

I changed the project workspace settings in Xcode between Legacy build and new build system. I still get error.

I tried to add the following to the pod file, and still get error

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.44'
```

And even all proposed solutions in here
[How to fix build error with FBSDKLoginKit in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986325/how-to-fix-build-error-with-fbsdkloginkit-in-xcode)

The error that I get is

```
No known class method for selector 'dictionary:setObject:forKey:'
```

I also tried to change the Firebase version and the Facebook Flutter login version in pub spec file (between 1.1.1 and 1.2.0 because I do not want to use AndroidX) but still getting the error.

Note that I updated Xcode to latest version, and error was not fixed.

I changed the iOS deployment version in Xcode for all pods to version 8. And error not fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE (JULY 2020)**

You can use a new package that works for both Android and iOS:
[flutter_login_facebook](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login_facebook)

If you want to use the [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login), below is a solution:

**UPDATE (APRIL 2020)**

1. Add [flutter_facbook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) version 3.0.0 from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) to your flutter project
2. Create your app on [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com) and configure your flutter app accordingly
3. Change your iOS target version to 9 in Xcode
4. Open in terminal the `Podfile.lock` which is located in the iOS folder of your flutter project and change all facebook api versions to 5.8.0. If the `Podfile.lock` does not exist, run your app once (so the file is created) and after it fires an error edit `Podfile.lock` then run it again. If your app still fails, run `pod install` manually form terminal.

---

There are two problems:

1. the compatibility between Facebook Login API and Firebase.
2. iOS update to version 13.x.

In pubspec.yaml file updated the firebase version to latest version.
Also, I am using version 1.2.0 for facebook login but still 1.1.1 works.

```
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
flutter_facebook_login: ^1.2.0
flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.3.1
```

I opened Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode (located in iOS folder inside flutter project), then File->WorkSpace settings, and selected New Build System option.

For all pods, change iOS deployment version to 8.0 (or above).

Now the application builds successfully and runs on iOS. But I get CancelledByUser each time I click on the Login with Facebook button.

This is a bug when having iOS update 13.x running the facebook login api.
I found a turnaround that made the login works.

```
final facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
```

Comment: Since my app works both on android and IOS, I had to add code to check if running on IOS and execute `facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
`.

Comment: I did the exact same thing, Apple rejects the app saying Facebook login doesn't work. Apparently, in release mode, it only shows a white page and doesn't work.

Comment: @SinaSeirafi please inform us about the alternative solution if you find one.

Comment: I am getting the same issue as @SinaSeirafi. Please let me know if you find a solution..

Comment: @user2570135 I found a solution, please read my updated answer

Comment: @SinaSeirafi check my updated answer for a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use my function as it works on both android and iOS and also registers the user in firebase console.

I have simply opening the login page in the WebView and when the user register himself, I am storing the credential in the firebase and then printing his name .

```
 final FacebookLogin fblogin = FacebookLogin();
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 
 Future loginwihFacebook() async {
   

fblogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
final result = await fblogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"]);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    final token = result.accessToken.token;
    await auth.signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token));

    var url =
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,picture,last_name,email&access_token=$token';
    var graphapiresponse = await http.get(url);
    var profileData = jsonDecode(graphapiresponse.body);      
    var name = profileData["name"];
    print(name);
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    print("cancelled by user");
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    print("error");
    break;
}


 }
```